# PIC QEI encouter values being weird

Tags: pic, encoder

I'm getting weird values when using the QEI on the dspic33. The QEI counter goes up to about 32700 then goes to negative 32650 and starts decrementing  to 0 where it starts from 32700 and starts increasing again. I was wondering why the QEI is going weird negative decrease. I have attached the code where i intialize the QEI and how i get the value. Could it be a weird casting or bit shift going on.

```
void QEI2_Init(){

PMD3bits.QEI2MD = 0;
// QEI CONTROL REGISTER
QEI2CONbits.QEIEN = 1;     
QEI2CONbits.QEISIDL = 1;
QEI2CONbits.PIMOD = 0;
QEI2CONbits.IMV =0;
QEI2CONbits.INTDIV = 0;
QEI2CONbits.CNTPOL = 0;
QEI2CONbits.GATEN = 0;
QEI2CONbits.CCM = 0;        // 00 = quadrature encoder mode

//QEI1IOC = 0;
// QEI I/O Control Register
QEI2IOCbits.QCAPEN = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.FLTREN = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.QFDIV = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.OUTFNC = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.SWPAB = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.HOMPOL = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.IDXPOL = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.QEBPOL = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.QEAPOL = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.HOME = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.INDEX = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.QEB = 0;
QEI2IOCbits.QEA = 0;

// QEIxSTAT: QEI STATUS REGISTERS (REGISTER 17-3)

//QEI1STAT = 0;
QEI2STATbits.PCHEQIRQ = 0;
QEI2STATbits.PCHEQIEN = 0;
QEI2STATbits.PCLEQIRQ = 0;
QEI2STATbits.PCLEQIEN = 0;
QEI2STATbits.POSOVIEN = 0;
QEI2STATbits.PCIIRQ = 0;
QEI2STATbits.PCIIEN = 0;
QEI2STATbits.VELOVIRQ = 0;
QEI2STATbits.VELOVIEN = 0;
QEI2STATbits.HOMIRQ = 0;
QEI2STATbits.HOMIEN = 0;
QEI2STATbits.IDXIRQ = 0;
QEI2STATbits.IDXIEN = 0;

POS2HLD = 0;
POS2CNTL = 0;   
VEL2CNT = 0;    
printf("QEI Init Done\n");

 }

void calculateEncoderPos()
 {
    qelo2 = POS2CNTL;
    qehi2 = POS2HLD;
   encoder.encoder2Count =  (long int)qehi2 << 15 | qelo2;
   printf ("Pos Low:%d \t", qelo2);        
   printf ("Pos High:%d \t", qehi2);
   printf("encoder2Pos:%ld\n", encoder.encoder2Count);
}
```

Comment: You've declared your variable(s) as signed integer(s). Declares them as `unsigned` and you won't get any negative numbers. Also, read up on the difference between signed & unsigned integers ...

Comment: wouldnt it need to be signed so that it can take into account negative values when going counterclockwise

Comment: The direction of motion affects the sign of the incremental change in the position.

Comment: changed them to unsigned integer but now when it gets to 65536 it goes back down to 32768 when it should be going up to least 4294967296 since the variable is uint32, is there an issue with the bit shifting?

Comment: Check the width of the counter register.  It certainly sounds like a 16-bit register that's rolling over from 0xffff to 0x0000 (or 0x7fff to 0x8000, in your first example).

Comment: the width of the counter register is 32 bits but it's made up of 2 16 bit registers

Comment: seems like something is wrong with the bit shifting as it gives a 16 bit value instead of creating a 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

changed variables to unsigned and changed bit shifting to ((uint32_t) qehi2 << 16) | qelo2. These changes helped fix the issue